# What is an IT Artefact

Tags: research

I am going to be starting my dissertation soon in MSc Cyber Security.  The supervisor keeps asking me 'What will be your IT artefact?' and to be honest I have no idea what he is actually asking me.  I understand the words, and I have Googled it (to some extent) but it's not clear to me what he is expecting.

Any help welcomed.

Comment: Hi Liqua, welcome to the site! Do you mean "Artifact" or "Artefact"? I've never heard of the latter, although it may be a term I'm unfamiliar with.

Comment: Hello Cowthulhu,

I can only go off what he wrote, sorry.  

Googling it I found this:

artefact
/ˈɑːtɪfakt/
noun: artefact; plural noun: artefacts; noun: artifact; plural noun: artifacts

    1.
    an object made by a human being, typically one of cultural or historical interest.
    "gold and silver artefacts"
    2.
    something observed in a scientific investigation or experiment that is not naturally present but occurs as a result of the preparative or investigative procedure.
    "the curvature of the surface is an artefact of the wide-angle view"

Comment: Also I submitted a proposed edit to your title that I think will make the question easier to understand without clicking on it.

Comment: You know what - I'm actually just used to spelling it the other way, it looks like they're both valid. Learned something new - thanks for clarifying!

Comment: This might be a US / UK thing :)  (I am from the UK)

Also, how to I see your suggested title change so I can edit it?

Comment: I'm not super certain, although I think this link should have instructions (may not be up to date): https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/

Comment: @Liqua, if the supervisor/instructor's first language is not English it could be just be a language problem. Or, sometimes using words in new ways is to help you practice thinking a little and practice connecting ideas instead of mindlessly memorizing facts. If you tried, can't figure it out, you can let the instructor know what you did but could not figure it out, and ask if they could explain.

Comment: This is not a language problem, but a gap between two approaches: practical information systems management and the scientific research of it. It's in well established, widely used scientific terminology, as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

By dictionary definition, an *artefact* (UK) or an *artifact* (US) is

> 1. an object made by a human being, typically one of cultural or historical interest. "gold and silver artefacts"
> 2. something observed in a scientific investigation or experiment that is not naturally present but occurs as a result of the
>      preparative or investigative procedure. "the curvature of the surface
>      is an artefact of the wide-angle view"

Your supervisor probably has a *design science* methodology background and expects your work will be build on this methodology, too.  **An *IT artifact* is a *design artifact* in the field of *information systems (research)*.**

The term  is widely used in information systems research. Reading through e.g. *Hevner, A., March, S. T., Park, J., & Ram, S. (2004). [Design Science in Information Systems Research](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.103.1725&rep=rep1&type=pdf). MIS quarterly, 28(1), 75-105.* should give you a good grounding on the subject. Here, an IT artifact could be many different things:

> The realm of IS research is at the confluence of people,
>   organizations, and technology (Davis and Olson 1985; Lee 1999). IT
>   artifacts are broadly defined as *constructs* (vocabulary and symbols),
>   *models* (abstractions and representations), *methods* (algorithms and
>   practices), and *instantiations*  (implemented  and  prototype 
>   systems). These are concrete  prescriptions  that enable  IT
>   researchers and practitioners to understand and address the problems
>   inherent in developing and successfully  implementing  information 
>   systems within  organizations  ([March  and  Smith  1995](http://www.siks.nl/RM%20M%20nov%202006/research%20%20paper%20marchsmithdssarticle.pdf); [Nunamaker et
>   al. 1991a](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/58d8/0963de554886910e878c6ad3b515fd600cdf.pdf)). - -
>
> Design  science,  as  the  other  side  of  the  IS research cycle,
>   creates and evaluates IT artifacts intended  to  solve  identified
>   organizational  problems.  Such artifacts are represented in a
>   structured  form  that  may  vary  from  software,  formal logic,
>   and rigorous   mathematics   to   informal natural  language
>   descriptions.    A  mathematical basis for design allows many types of
>   quantitative evaluations of an IT artifact, including
>   optimization proofs,  analytical  simulation,  and
>   quantitative comparisons with alternative designs.  The
>   further evaluation  of  a  new  artifact  in  a  given  organizational
>   context  affords  the  opportunity  to  apply empirical  and
>   qualitative  methods.

Comment: In other words, do not Google it, but [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.fi/) it.

Comment: Thank you - appreciated the reference too.